# Using Django application models in python file

Tags: python, django, module, models

I'm using Django 1.9.4, I made my own project by

```
django-admin.py startproject mynewproject
```

and I registered it in mysite/settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'mynewproject.apps.MynewprojectConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

In this project I have created a model named Attack with different fields, so that mynewproject/models.py is like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
# Create your models here.

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Attack(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I also made a new "main" file in mynewproject/saveDB.py:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mynewproject.settings")

from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()
from django.apps import AppConfig


import django
django.setup()

from models import models as c
dir(c) #Exception

# your imports, e.g. Django models
from django.db import models
from models import Attack #Exception


attackDB = Attack.objects.create(name=attack)
attackDB.save()
```

However when I run the saveDB.py code I get this exception:

```
File "/home/me/django-user/firstProject/mysite/mynewproject/saveDB.py", line 401, in <module>
  from models import Attack
File "/home/me/django-user/firstProject/mysite/mynewproject/models.py", line 8, in <module>
  class Attack(models.Model):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 102, in __new__
  "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class models.Attack doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I tried to import from mynewproject.models but apparently I can't:

```
ImportError: No module named 'mynewproject'
```

How I'm supposed to use models and then call save?

Comment: It is better to create a custom management command for such purposes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Even when trying that example I get stuck at this line:

    `from polls.models import Poll`

  
   `ImportError: No module named 'polls'`